# I want to mention that replying in Japanese is ok

Tags: grammar

I will post an ad about an item for sale. I mention everything about the item in English, but at the end of the ad I want to say, "It's ok to reply in Japanese."

Is it proper grammar to say "返信は日本語でも大丈夫です!" if an ad is posted online and you are referring to people responding to the ad?

Comment: Could you dress the question up a bit, put a bit more in the title so we can tell what you're asking about, give a little more context on where you want to use this phrase?

Comment: Ok... I will post an ad about an item for sale. I mention everything about the item in English, but at the end of the ad I want to say, "It's ok to reply in Japanese."

Comment: If they can read the English that far, they can read the last sentence in English, too. But, if you want to be nice, Ben's suggestion, 「お問い合わせ」、 should work. Or even what I'll add in my reply.

Answer (score 8):

**ご返信**は日本語でも大丈夫です！ sounds much better. However, 返信 means an answer to spoken or written communication. It is not used to "answer an ad" (that would be 応募する). お問合せ (enquiry, question) is a better call here:
お問い合わせは日本語でも大丈夫です!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is absolutely proper. (if original word "reply" is appropriate for your ads)

For ads, there is a commercial expression.

> 日本語対応可能です。

But I like your original sentence :)

Answer (score 1):

How proper do you want it to be?

I think it would be understood, but it is a little odd. It feels like you're saying it's okay to send the reply using Japanese.

Referring to the [question on 返信 vs. 返事](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17359/word-difference-question-reply-%E8%BF%94%E4%BA%8B-vs-%E8%BF%94%E4%BF%A1)、 返信 is about a communication activity, not about the information itself.

I think I'd use a bit of honorific and stick with 返事〜

> 日本語でもご返事していただけます。

But even that depends on context.

(yabut)

See this:

https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1210045367

「返事していただけます。」 would probably more than polite enough, but, after talking with my daughter, I am convinced that 「返事」 is even more out of place than 「返信」。 If I understand this correctly, 「返事」 would be appropriate when you pretty much expect an answer from the reader, as in, say, an on-line-quiz.

(end yabut)

(additional information)

Given that this is a classified ad, if you are worried that an all-English ad will scare away some potential buyers, Ben's suggestion about 「お問い合わせ」 is quite workable. Also, you could simply leave out the implicit verb for contacting and say, 「日本語で大丈夫」 or 「日本語でも、どうぞ。」。

It may feel a little abrupt, but the Japanese people who are reading your ad in English will, on the contrary, feel it a little odd if the last sentence only is in perfect Japanese.

(end additional information)

Comment: > "日本語でもご返事していただけます。" isn't correct, unfortunately.
ご返信する is humble, not honorific speech, and thus shouldn't be used to adress other's actions. 返信する is one of those verbs which are rarely used outside of requests (ご返信いただけますようお願いします) and set phrases like "thank you for your response" (ご返信ありがとうございます). Therefore, the proper honorific form （ご）返信なさる is seldomly heard. If you use 返信 at all (and as I wrote above, it doesn't really fit the context) you'll have to write something like
ご返信は日本語でもいただけます or ご返信は日本語でも大丈夫です.
Using 大丈夫 makes it sound more relaxed and "younger", especially if combined with an

Comment: @Ben (1) Read before responding. You even quote my suggestion correctly and then you respond as if I said something else. (2) Context is far more than you seem to understand. I did not recommend 「ご返信」、 but I have, in fact, seen it in business correspondence.

Comment: んー…でもやっぱり「日本語でもご返事していただけます。」はあきませんよね。。

Comment: 家の娘に聞いたら、違和感ありそうですね。調べたらこれが出てきました： https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1210045367 、 ただ、何の返事かという問題が感じられるのです。「問い合わせ」という単語が一番らしい。